# sql failure converting to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL server Manager 2008.

Ive recently changed a stored procedure to look at a different table.

Since then I keep receiving the same error:

"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BC8018' to data type int."

Now I split my query down to the root to find where this problem occurs and sure enough its happening on the JOIN to my new table.

Now I compared the only field Im using in the table and both Pareto and NewPareto are ints.

Heres the code:

```
SELECT i.Acct,
   i.Name, 
   i.Document, 
   i.Part, 
   i.Qty, 
   i.Unit, 
   dbo.PeriodInsert.NewPareto,
   i.pg,
   i.[DateTime],
   i.BinSeqNo

FROM   
OPENQUERY(SACBAUTO, 'SELECT dbo.iHeads.acct,
                            dbo.iHeads.name,
                            dbo.iLines.Document,
                            dbo.iLines.Part,
                            dbo.iLines.Pg,
                            dbo.iLines.Qty,
                            dbo.iLines.unit,
                            dbo.iHeads.[DateTime], 
                            dbo.iLines.BinSeqNo 
                     FROM Autopart.dbo.iheads INNER JOIN Autopart.dbo.iLines ON 
                     Autopart.dbo.Iheads.document = autopart.dbo.iLines.document
                     WHERE dbo.iLines.Pg not in (''60'',''61'',''62'')

                      ') i
left JOIN
dbo.PeriodInsert
ON 
i.Part collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = dbo.PeriodInsert.NewPareto 
WHERE
 (i.[DateTime] BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-08-23') AND
 i.Acct = '1557'
```

Please remember this I a break down of the original stored procedure but this is where the root of it occurs.  I find it strange, the Original table called NEWpareto using the field pareto is an int aswell.
Any thoughts why this thing has suddenly stopped working just because of a table?

If you require more info just let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbo.iLines.Part` is not an int - it has a collation - so if NewPareto is, then you are trying to convert it to an int to do the join.  Search that field for "BC8018" and check it's valid. If it is, then you will have to join `i.Part` to `convert(nvarchar(...), dbo.PeriodInsert.NewPareto)`

Comment: of course im matching it wrong, sorry just woke up.  silly me